# Unable to create database in postgresql in ubuntu

Tags: sql, linux, postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I try to create a database. After reading around, I saw two methods:

Method 1:

```
xxxxxx:~$ sudo -i -u postgres
postgres$xxxx:~$ createdb mydb1
```

Method 2:

```
xxxxxx:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
postgres:# CREATE DATABASE mydb2
```

If I do method 1, the database `mydb1` gets created. And when I am in `postgres:#` and do this `\list`, I can see `mydb1` being listed.
However, if I do method 2, after the end line above, there is no error whatsoever. But when I do `\list` in `postgres:#`, I don't the database `mydb2` being listed.

My first time trying to set up a postgresql database. Please, if someone could explain what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In psql you need to end the sql with the semicolon:

```
create database mydb2;
```